# How to setup a background image in delphi while using FMX

Tags: delphi, background, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I tried to use `Timage` component to setup the background (as exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849859/setting-up-background-images-for-forms-in-delphi)) but I have figure out that `Timage` doesn't have `Picture` properties anymore so I can't load it, is there any other way to load it?

I use rad studio xe7, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: That sounds extremely peculiar. Are you using VCL or FMX? XE7 VCL TImage has a Picture property for me.

Comment: The VCL `TImage` does indeed have a `Picture` property. Which means that you are using FMX. So, do you want to know how to display a background, or do you want to know how to use `TImage`?

Comment: There is a documentation for the component (and a lot more) here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Objects.TImage_Properties

Comment: I want to know how to display a background when using fmx .

Comment: When using FMX (depending on the version), you can make a background on the form itself without a separate control.

Comment: I'll try with Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('MyImage.jpg') , but it doesn't get deplayed in my properties either the bitmap property.

Comment: Why don't you ask that question, instead of this one. I suggest that you start again with a major edit. Ask about displaying a background on an FMX form, rather than about TImage. You might take a look at this: http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/codeexamples/en/FMX.Mobile.Forms_Sample_(Object_Pascal)

Answer (score 3):

You can still use TImage in FMX. It has just been extended to support the large variety of resolutions when developing for multiple targets. Use the property `MultiResBitmap` to load your image, then set `WrapMode` to e.g. `stretch` (if you want your image to be stretched).

Comment: That's not true. The FMX `TImage` has not been extended. It's a totally different control from the VCL `TImage`.

Comment: I meant 'Extended' from a user perspective. It is still there and it can still do similar things as the VCL TImage, but the 'Bitmap' has been 'extended' to handle multiple resolutions.